# Slideshow Image not scalling with browser window

Tags: css

I have a slideshow in my website that will not scale to the browser.
What happens: When the browser is reduced to 414 px it renders
correctly. When I drag the browser window larger the slideshow image
size remains the same. Refreshing the browser makes it render correctly.
Also during the increase in browser size it's not a smooth transition.
You can see it here. http://comrefhvac.com 
Thank you in advance.
RichM

Comment: we need to see your code.

Comment: Probably your slideshow plugin does not adjust its self on window resize.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Bring up my url in a browser and view the source page.

Answer (score 0):

How to fix the issue is a different question, and one that requires that we look at your code. If you simply want to know why, then it's because the styling for the slideshow is dynamically applied via javascript and it looks like the author of the plugin only considered the initial page load and no the `window.resize` event.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know how to remedy the situation using your javascript suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm cool with that. Try this, go to my website then take the browser down to 414 px and you will see a gap between the slideshow and the text below. Then refresh the page and it will render as it should. Then maximize the browser and you will see that the slideshow container does not expand to the proper size which is set in my css at 440 x 800 px. Thanks for being honest, hope your head doesn't hurt this AM Jeff. RichM